# A textbook with a proof of the Rank Theorem using only Banach's Fixed Point Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, alternative-proof, fixed-point-theorems

It is well known that the Rank Theorem for $C^1$ maps can be obtained as a consequence of the Implicit Mapping Theorem and the Inverse Mapping Theorem for $C^1$ maps. See for example [Zorich vol 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540874518).

It is also well known that the Implicit and Inverse Mapping theorems are a consequence of the Banach's Fixed Point Theorem. See [Pugh](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387952977) for a proof of Implicit Mapping Theorem directly from Banach's Fixed Point Theorem. See [Rudin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070856133) for a proof of the Inverse Mapping Theorem directly from Banach's Fixed Point Theorem.

Obviously, for what was exposed in the previous paragraph, a proof (or several proofs) of Rank Theorem for $C^1$ mapping by means of the Banach Fixed Point Theorem exists. In other words, the affirmations of the Banach fixed point theorem and Rank Theorem for $C^1$ mapping  are not independent.

In view of these considerations, my question is as follows. Is there any textbook with a proof of the rank theorem using Banach's Fixed Point Theorem?

In the absence of a textbook, I would be very grateful for articles and lecture notes.